# Retornar somente o registro mais novo de cada autor

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma tabela com os seguintes campos:

```
id, texto, autor_id, data
```

Preciso que os registros sejam agrupados por `autor_id` (pois tem vários textos com o mesmo autor) e me retorne em ordem crescente os mais novos somente. Estou usando o Lavarel e o meu código do Eloquent esta o seguinte:

```
Discursos::take(10)->distinct('membro_id')->orderBy('data_discurso', 'asc')->get();
```

Se coloco `groupBy` no lugar de `distinct` está me retornando somente o mais antigo dos registros. Como fazer ao contrário?

O que eu estou fazendo é retornando uma lista de texto no qual o autor faz tempo que não cadastra, quero que me retorne para saber qual autor faz mais tempo que não cadastra algo.

Comment: Explicando... Tenho uma tabela com o registro de discursos, o que eu preciso é de um controle no qual irá me listar os discusantes que a maior tempo não tem discurso cadastrado, para que eu possa avisá-los que faz tempo que ele não cadastra um discurso. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query que você precisa, em SQL puro, é assim:

```sql
SELECT membro_id, MAX(data_discurso)
FROM tabela
GROUP BY membro_id
ORDER BY MAX(data_discurso) DESC, membro_id
```

Se precisar de mais algum campo no `SELECT` (por exemplo, o próprio texto), será necessário usar uma subquery.

Utilizando Eloquent a query acima ficaria assim:

```
$resultado = DB::table('tabela')->select(DB::raw('membro_id, MAX(data_discurso)'))
                     ->groupBy('membro_id')
                     ->orderBy(DB::raw('MAX(data_discurso) DESC, membro_id'))->get();
```

**Editado:** O Eloquent aceita as expressões do Query builder, como o whereIn, basta você editar conforme sua necessidade a sub query:

```
Discursos::whereIn(DB::raw('SELECT MAX(data_discurso) FROM discursos GROUP BY membro_id'))
```

Para mais informações consulte a documentação:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Comment: Obrigado, @gmsantos! Estou marcando a resposta como wiki comunitário para não ganhar pontos com ela, já que só metade é minha :)

Comment: Consegui o que preciso fazendo o seguinte com Query Builder: DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM discursos 
WHERE data_discurso IN (SELECT MAX(data_discurso) FROM discursos GROUP BY 
membro_id) ORDER BY data_discurso ASC')); Não encontrei uma solução com o Eloquent, o duro que essa query não trás automaticamente os meus relacionamentos que tenho nessa tabela, coisa que no eloquent faz. Tem alguma forma de colocar essa query no Eloquent?

Comment: Eu não domino o eloquent, então não posso ajudar muito...

Comment: Editei a resposta anterior.

Comment: @gmsantos agora a resposta ficou mais sua que minha :) se quiser postar uma resposta separada e ganhar pontos com ela, faça isso e me avise, que eu apago a minha.

Comment: @bfavaretto sem problemas, pode deixar assim mesmo

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está pedindo que a ordenação dos dados seja baseada no campo `data_discurso` em ordem **ascendente** (do mais antigo ao mais novo), quando na verdade ela deveria ser **descendente** (do mais novo ao mais antigo). O método `get()` retorna <strike>sempre o primeiro resultado da pesquisa</strike> um grupo de dez registros (pelo uso de `take(10)`) e, neste caso, o primeiro registro deverá ser o mais antigo. Para corrigir, basta mudar o seguinte trecho

```
->orderBy('data_discurso', 'asc')
```

para

```
->orderBy('data_discurso', 'desc')
```

Comment: Mesmo com a ordem alterada não me trás os registros como preciso, trás sempre a primeira data de cada discurso. Veja o meu comentário na resposta do colega abaixo, tenho a query SQL para fazer o que preciso. Obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Ordene as datas em ordem descendente:

```
Discursos::take(10)->distinct('membro_id')->orderBy('data_discurso', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: A resposta fica mais completa se você explicar o *porquê* da sua solução. Colocar links pra documentação também valoriza. Confira o guia [answer].

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em português! Seria interessante se você explicasse como o código postado responde à pergunta.

Comment: Também gostaria de ver explicações sobre o funcionamento desse código. Quanto mais detalhada sua resposta mais fácil será de alguém que venha no futuro e queira aprender um pouco mais sobre o [tag:laravel] conseguir entender o que fazer, como fazer e porque fazer.

Comment: O groupBy ou distinct me dá a mesma saída de dados. Obrigado